# Navigate to a page in the same stack not refreshing the page - react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two stacks(Assume NotificationStack & HomeStack) in react navigation to use for bottom navigation bar. In one stack i have a certain number of screens. I have few same screens in both stacks(ex:JobDetail in both stacks) and so when i tried to switch between the two stacks(from the bottom navigation bar) if a screen present in both  is active , when i switch it doesn't reload the page like usual navigation (navigate or reset). I am a noob to Complex React Navigation practices.

```
 const NotificationStack = StackNavigator({
          NotificationHome: {
            screen: Notifications,
            navigationOptions: { header: null }
          },
          JobDetail: {
            screen: JobDetail,
            navigationOptions: { header: null }
          },

          ViewCandidate: {
            screen: ViewCandidate,
            navigationOptions: { header: null }
          },


          Payment: { screen: Payment, navigationOptions: { header: null } }
        });
```

Comment: What version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal "react-navigation": "version": "2.5.5